# overlay text and images using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I am writing my thesis presentation using beamer template. I would like to create the following thing:

- slide 1 -> shows a simple image
- slide 2 -> shows a different image with a bullet list positioned where i want
- slide 3 -> same as slide 2

I have red that this can be done by using tikz, but i don't seem to understand how it works. I have used the \only environment for the images and it works, but i need some help for the tikz part. Can any of you give me some tips?

Below the latex code i am working on:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,oldgerm}

\newcommand{\testcolor}[1]{\colorbox{#1}{\textcolor{#1}{test}}~\texttt{#1}}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\hrefcol}[2]{\textcolor{cyan}{\href{#1}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{}
    \only<1>{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \only<2->{\begin{tikzpicture}
        {\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
        \node [rectangle, text width=3cm] at (15,9) {\begin{itemize}
 \item item1
 \item item2
 \end{itemize}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Which Tikz part do you mean?

Comment: TikZ is a drawing program/language for LaTeX. You must mean something else as you do not write anything about drawing.

Comment: You don't need the `only` in your code. It isn't doing anything whatsoever.

Comment: To combine text and images with tikz, put text in one node and  \includegraphics in another node, and place them where you want them relative to each other.

Comment: @cfr i use the \only command because i want the changes happening on the same slide number.

Comment: Still I have no idea how your presented slides shall look like. Can you add a sketch, please? And some representative (simple) Tikz code? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO I added a tentative code using tikz with the resulting output. Moreover i specify the image to be in the center. Why it is aligned at the left side?

Comment: @AndreaTantucci You probably want to take a look at the `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}` library. Can you make a test document which we can compile without having your special theme? Also `\end{document}` is missing.

Comment: If you want to use page nodes like `current page.center` you have to use the `remember picture` option.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it should be okay now

Comment: @AndreaTantucci Well, now you've posted different code, but `\only` did nothing whatsoever in the code you originally posted because you used the same overlay specification for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use page nodes like `current page.center` you have to use the remember picture option.

I'd either combine this with the `overlay` option or with `visible on=...` from the `overlay-beamer-styles` library to prevent other content of the slide from jumping around between overlays.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{oldgerm}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \node<1-> at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
     \node<2->[rectangle, text width=3cm] at (10,-3) {
        \begin{itemize}
           \item item1
           \item item2
         \end{itemize}
     };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the image is positioned in the center of the slide. Now i am trying to add a bullet list to the image side but it gives me the error: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. I edited the original code with the new one. Can you give me some advices?

Comment: @AndreaTantucci See my updated answer

Comment: Ok thank you i will accept this answer. If you can i would like to ask you another question. What i would like to do is to have in the first slide an image centered (example-image-a) for example, while in slide 2 i would like to have example-image-b with the bullet list. I have to create another \begin{}/end{} tikzpicture or i can include everything inside the one i already have?

Comment: @AndreaTantucci If you want image a only on the first overlay, use `\node<1> ...` and then `\node<2-> ...` with another image

Comment: ok perfect. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @AndreaTantucci You're welcome!